# Character '^' with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to have the character `^` taking into account when doing regxep matching in javascript? It seems to be a special character, as:

```
"x^2".match( /[A-z]+[0-9]*/)
```

returns:

```
["x^2"]
```

Comment: What do you exactly want ?

Comment: What are you expecting? The `^` character isn't necessary for a match in your example.

Comment: `[A-z]` is equivalent to `[\x41-\x7a]`, which is equivalent to `[A-Z[\\\]^_\`a-z]`.

Comment: @dystroy I want to have ["x"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"^" is not treated as special, it simply falls between "A" and "z" in ascii (see http://www.asciitable.com/). Try matching against the pattern [a-zA-Z] instead to limit to just the english alphabet.

```
"x^2".match(/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*/) // returns ["x"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape any special character with `\` to use it literally.

```
"x^2".match(/[A-z]\^[0-9]*/)
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to have only "real" chars of the alphabet, don't use `[A-z]` which is too wide. You might want

```
 "x^2".match(/\w+/)
```

or

```
"x^2".match(/[A-Za-z]+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape it, just like you do for every other special character:

```
match( /\^/ )
```

Answer (score 1):

`[A-z]` does not stand for `[A-Za-z]`! See the unicode table.

To use a literal `^` in your pattern you must escape it because this character has a special meaning in a regex.

```
/[A-Za-Z]\^[0-9]/
```

OR

```
/[a-z]\^[0-9]/i
```

More informations [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)